# Strava API - Retrieve activity photos with metadata

Tags: api, strava

I'm trying to use the Strava API to acquire the pictures of an activity and to get their location - based on the metadata (similar to what is performed on apps like [www.relive.cc](http://www.relive.cc)).

I'm facing two issues :

1. Only the primary photos is shown in the retrieved data from the API, although the activity has several photos.
2. The picture I manage to get ([sample here](https://dgtzuqphqg23d.cloudfront.net/z0bUndbpffbmkOD8HSzQ37TYaXLxmHy1JmKOz-B8ibc-2048x1536.jpg)) does not include any metadata, so I'm not able to retrieve any location information.

Answer (score 0):

did you have any progress on that? Im researching how could I have the activity photos initially. Later on, photo metadata would be also nice.

Comment: No updates on this. I assume there would be a way, but did not manage yet.